# Finding or creating an object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My domain model and its associations are as follows:

- `Customer` has many `Region`s
- `Region` has many `Location`s

Our client supplies us with a CSV file that has the following columns:

- Customer name
- Region name
- Location name

  - Latitude
  - Longitude
  - ...

Based on this information, I have to find or create the customer by name, find or create the region by name, and finally find or update the location by name.

I have tried the following:

```
var customer = from c in _data.Customer
               where c.Name == cells[0]
               select c;

if (customer == null)
    customer = new Customer(...);
```

I would follow the same pattern for finding or creating/updating the region and location, however, the problem I run into is that the type of the LINQ query cannot be converted to a `Customer`-object on line `customer = new customers();`. I need to reference this `customer` object later so I can't have two separate variables.

How would I accomplish this in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code

```
var customer = from c in _data.Customer
               where c.Name == cells[0]
               select c;
```

Returns all the customers who has the `Name` equals `cells[0]` so the return type will be `IQueryable<Customer>` not a sigle `Customer` (that's why the `customer = new Customer(...)` doesn't work).

What you need is to call `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` (depending on your requirements.) on it if you want to have back one `Customer`.

So this should work

```
var customer = (from c in _data.Customer
               where c.Name == cells[0]
               select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var customer = (from c in _data.Customer
               where c.Name == cells[0]
               select c).FirstOrDefault();

if (customer == null)
    customer = new Customer(...);
```

Comment: If you need to ensure that there is at most one record returned you should use SingelOrDefault instead of FirstOrDefault

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! That did it as well! :-)